# PHPMailer cannot substitite sender?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Trying to send mail from site by PHPMailer:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->isSMTP();    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.ru'; // Specify main SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'mylogin'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';   // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('sender_from_site@gmail.com', 'User on site');
    $mail->addAddress('recipient@yandex.ru', 'Mail reader'); // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true);          // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    imail->send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This code produces phpmailerException exception with the following info:

> The following From address failed: sender_from_site@gmail.com : MAIL
>   FROM command failed,Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.
>   ,553,5.7.1SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Sender
>   address rejected: not owned by auth user.  SMTP code: 553 Additional
>   SMTP info: 5.7.1

Ok, but it's not an error - it's my idea to get email from site same as sender directly did.

How to substitute real sender?

Comment: Add setReplyTo !

Comment: That obviously should not be possible and is not possible with any decent email service. It would allow anyone to send out email messages with any sender information which certainly is nothing anyone would want, except for people following criminal goals. Any decent email service will refuse relaying attempts and most refuse sender identities apart from the account that authenticated for the usage of the smtp service.

Comment: @MathieuDormeval:
Adding `$mail->ClearReplyTos(); $mail->addReplyTo('mylogin@yandex.ru');` just before `$mail->setFrom` produce the same exception

Comment: @arkascha: You are not right. PHP mail can do it - just add single header to email: `$headers = "From: \"$from_user\" <$from_email>"'`. It works brilliant! The reason why I don't use mail() - it can't work with secure connections.

Comment: This is security from SMTP. Use a correct and valid mail account from your registrar and add a addReplyTo to let us make answers. This is the way to acieve the goal (like noreply@yandex.ru).

Comment: @MathieuDormeval: I use here (instead of 'mylogin') my real personal email account exists more than 5 years.

Comment: Certainly you can specify any sender you like in an email you are _trying_ to send. That has nothing to do with php. What I said is that any decent email service (so SMTP server here) will reject such a message.